# json_encode gives no valid json string

Tags: php, json

I'n having this problem with a json string which I'n generating with json_encode.
This is the input:

```
stdClass Object
(
[titles] => stdClass Object
    (
        [nl] => test
        [en] => test
    )

[contents] => stdClass Object
    (
        [nl] => <p>\n   test</p>\n
        [en] => <p>\n   test</p>\n
    )

[languages] => stdClass Object
    (
        [0] => nl
        [1] => en
    )

)
```

and I put this in my database using this SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO `pages`
                    (`title`, `content`, `lang`)
                    VALUES('{"nl":"test","en":"test"}', '{"nl":"<p>\\n\ttest<\/p>\\n","en":"<p>\\n\ttest<\/p>\\n"}', '{"0":"nl","1":"en"}')
```

As far as I can see, nothing wrong, it's all stored in the database, no problems.

Then I try to get the output I get this for my content:

```
{"nl":"<p>n test</p>n","en":"<p>n   test</p>n"}
```

which results in:

```
(
[id] => 10
[title] => stdClass Object
    (
        [nl] => test
        [en] => test
    )

[content] => 
[lang] => stdClass Object
    (
        [0] => nl
        [1] => en
    )

[created] => 2012-10-24 11:49:52
)
```

So, my json string is invalid.
How is this possible?
I really have no idea what I've done wrong.

Comment: The output you say you get for your content is not the value your `INSERT` statement would have stored in the database, but even that is a valid JSON that decodes fine. You're mangling it somehow after you select it, post your actual code. Also, you should probably normalize your database schema and stop storing JSON in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! You're right! Stupid of me not to think of that, I always use a function for my `SELECT` statements, in this code I was using `stripslashes()` which apparently was making my json string  invalid because there were some `\n` things in it.
Thank you!